# MySQL send message after 3 minutes

Tags: mysql

On my website, users can send messages to each other. Private messaging is possible. and these are hosted in the message table. 
[Message Table](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/11/22/Rxytmn.png)

I would like to send 1 private message to every new user who is a member of the site. To do this, you only need to create an entry in the _message table.

```
 INSERT INTO message(from_user_id, to_user_id, text, created_at)
 SELECT user.id, new.id, "selam", created_at FROM user WHERE username = "admin"
```

So far so good went. But I want this message to be transmitted to the user after 2 minutes. How I can do this. Please give me a code sample.

In short;

I want an entry to be added to the _message table after 2 minutes when the user registers to the site.

I was only able to do so. I cannot send a message to the last user added to the _user table to be forwarded after 3 minutes.

```
 CREATE EVENT message
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS
DO
INSERT INTO message(from_user_id, to_user_id, text, created_at) SELECT user.id, new.id, "selam", created_at FROM user WHERE username = "admin"
```

Comment: You probably want to use a cron job that checks once per minute to see if any users created more than 2 minutes ago have received the welcome message, since you do store `created_at` in the user table. Alternatively, if you can configure the inbox to only show messages created in the past, you can choose a time in the future so the message won't be "delivered" until then.

Comment: Can you create a sample code for me?

Comment: You can use the MySQL Event Scheduler, you don't need to use cron.

Comment: @barmar Can you write me a short example for this?

Comment: @Barmar I updated my post. That's all I could do. Because the sample I want is not on the Internet.

Answer (score 0):

The `user` table needs to have a column that contains the time that the account was created. You can then test that column in your scheduled query.

You need to self-join the `user` table so you can get the ID of the new user and the admin user.

```
CREATE EVENT message
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE STARTS
DO
INSERT INTO message(from_user_id, to_user_id, text, created_at) 
SELECT admin.id, new.id, "selam", UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW())
FROM user AS admin
CROSS JOIN user AS new
WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, NOW(), FROM_UNIXTIME(new.creation_time)) == 2
AND admin.username = "admin"
```

Comment: Can you edit the code one last time by looking at the User table? Exactly how should I do it?  [User table](https://i.imgyukle.com/2019/11/24/RIP8J1.png) @barmar

Comment: I've added the functions to convert to/from Unix timestamp format.